# Find oldest for every joined document

Tags: mongodb, performance, collections, find

I have two collections, A and B. Each document in collection A corresponds to many documents in collection B. Documents in collection B have two important properties, "AID", the ID of the corresponding collection A document, and "date", something I want to sort by.

I now have a find query on collection A, which returns many documents in that collection. For each of the returned documents, I now want to find the oldest corresponding document in collection B.

So far, I used a for-each on my find query in collection A, and then used a find({"AID": doc._id}).sort({"date": 1}).limit(1) on collection B.

This is obviously super inefficient, since I have to go through my enormous collection B every single time for each document in collection A. Can I somehow simplify this into two aggregated queries only, perhaps using some kind of aggregate pipeline? How can I only traverse collection B once?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not solve it with schema? i.e. store document from B which meets the criteria in A.

Comment: Please provide some sample documents and expected result.

Comment: @Yahya Because I don't decide the database schema.